# Update one table reference id based on double select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, `t1`:

| ID | T2_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

and `t2`

| ID | PROP |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo |
| 1 | bar |

Is it possible to update all T2_IDs in first table based on double select, in word:

Update all T2_IDs to `(SELECT id FROM T2 WHERE prop = 'foo')`
WHERE T2_ID = `(SELECT id FROM T2 WHERE prop = 'bar')`

I have tried:

```
UPDATE T1 t1
SET t1.t2_id  = t2_new.id,
FROM SELECT ID
    FROM T2 t2_old 
    WHERE t2_old.prop = 'foo',
FROM SELECT ID
    FROM T2 t2_new
    WHERE t2_new.prop = 'bar',
WHERE 
    t2_old.id = t1.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there when you described it using words. Just use correlated sub-queries:

```sql
UPDATE T1
SET   t2_id = (SELECT id FROM T2 WHERE prop = 'foo')
WHERE t2_id = (SELECT id FROM T2 WHERE prop = 'bar');
```

However, since your `t2.id` values are both `1` for `foo` and `bar` you will not see any difference.

If instead, you had the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (ID, T2_ID) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE t2 (ID, PROP) AS
SELECT 2, 'foo' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'bar' FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the `UPDATE`, `t1` would contain:

| ID | T2_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ywSe4cV6)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use MERGE INTO - assuming there is just one 'foo' row in Table T2. If not - make sure you fetch just one in USING (sql)

```sql
MERGE INTO T1 t USING ( Select * From T2 ) x ON(x.PROP = 'foo')
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET   t.t2_id = x.id
WHERE t.T2_ID IN(Select ID From t2 Where PROP = 'bar');
```

.... which for sample data like this

```sql
/*  Table T1
        ID      T2_ID
---------- ----------
         1          1    <-- to be updated
         2          2    <-- to be updated
         3          3
         4          1    <-- to be updated
    Table T2
        ID PRO
---------- ---
         9 foo
         1 bar 
         2 bar   */
```

... results as:

```sql
/*  Table t1
        ID      T2_ID
---------- ----------
         1          9
         2          9
         3          3
         4          9  */
```